# Не могу установить GitHub Desktop под Linux

Tags: linux, git

Ставлю сборку GitHub Desktop под Linux. При установке `.deb` пакета выдаёт это:

```
Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 github-desktop : Зависит: libappindicator1 но он не может быть установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
```

Если что, ставлю по туториалу из [этой статьи](https://dev.to/rahedmir/is-github-desktop-available-for-gnu-linux-4a69). Также замечу, что раньше, где-то месяц назад всё прекрасно работало.

Comment: я вот даже не специалист, но сразу могу предсказать вопрос: какой линукс? какая версия? от какого пользователя происходит установка?

Comment: Kali Linux 2020.4, выполняю от root.

Comment: а вообще, судя по вопросу - у вас страшная русская убунта, в которой надо сделать что от вроде apt-get clean, чтобы сбросить кеш пакетов. Ошибка говорит о том, что система не может разобраться, что у неё тут в локальном репозитории - гугулите по ошибке, и будет вам инструкция, как решить проблему

Comment: ключевая фраза "у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты"

Comment: Да, я знаю, что пакет libappindicator1 сломан, но как его починить?

Comment: ну так, попробуйте этот способ: очистка кеша пакетов

Comment: Да, попробовал, не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: Попробуйте `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Ну то, что ты хочешь - работать не будет: https://repology.org/project/libappindicator/versions

Answer (score -2):

`rm /etc/apt/sources.list`

Нужно удалить файл `sources.list`. За него можно не волноваться, так как он создастся автоматически.

Comment: Интересная концепция, особенно в свете того, что корневой раздел (или как следствие _/etc_) может быть смонтирован в read-only.

Comment: Лучше `rm -rf / etc/apt/source.list` - так надёжнее. Только файлики важные сначала сохрани куда-нибудь на внешний носитель.